# Trying to concatenate multiple videos with multiple audio streams using ffmpeg

Tags: ffmpeg

I'm trying to concatenate 3 mp4 videos, each contains 3 audio streams using ffmpeg, since I couldn't merge them with other software because of differences in the codecs private data.

Since the files have different codecs I'm trying to use the concat video filter but I can't seem to get it to work. The output turns out to be an unplayable file. I'm trying to specify the input files, and every media stream, then telling the software to concatenate it and copy it to the output file.

```
ffmpeg -i A.mp4 -i B.mp4 -i C.mp4 -filter_complex  '[0:0] [0:1] [0:2] [0:3] [1:0] [1:1] [1:2] [1:3] [2:0] [2:1] [2:2] [2:3] concat=n=3:v=1:a=3 [v] [a1] [a2] [a3]'  -map '[v]' -map '[a1]' -map '[a2]'-map '[a3]' output.mp4
```

The complete log:

```
ffmpeg -i A.mp4 -i B.mp4 -i C.mp4 -filter_complex  '[0:0] [0:1] [0:2] [0:3] [1:0] [1:1] [1:2] [1:3] [2:0] [2:1] [2:2] [2:3] concat=n=3:v=1:a=3 [v] [a1] [a2] [a3]'  -map '[v]' -map '[a1]' -map '[a2]'-map '[a3]' output.mp4
ffmpeg version 4.1.1 Copyright (c) 2000-2019 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 8.2.1 (GCC) 20190212
  configuration: --enable-gpl --enable-version3 --enable-sdl2 --enable-fontconfig --enable-gnutls --enable-iconv --enable-libass --enable-libbluray --enable-libfreetype --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libopus --enable-libshine --enable-libsnappy --enable-libsoxr --enable-libtheora --enable-libtwolame --enable-libvpx --enable-libwavpack --enable-libwebp --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable-libxml2 --enable-libzimg --enable-lzma --enable-zlib --enable-gmp --enable-libvidstab --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvo-amrwbenc --enable-libmysofa --enable-libspeex --enable-libxvid --enable-libaom --enable-libmfx --enable-amf --enable-ffnvcodec --enable-cuvid --enable-d3d11va --enable-nvenc --enable-nvdec --enable-dxva2 --enable-avisynth
  libavutil      56. 22.100 / 56. 22.100
  libavcodec     58. 35.100 / 58. 35.100
  libavformat    58. 20.100 / 58. 20.100
  libavdevice    58.  5.100 / 58.  5.100
  libavfilter     7. 40.101 /  7. 40.101
  libswscale      5.  3.100 /  5.  3.100
  libswresample   3.  3.100 /  3.  3.100
  libpostproc    55.  3.100 / 55.  3.100
Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from 'A.mp4':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : mp42
    minor_version   : 512
    compatible_brands: isomiso2avc1mp41
    encoder         : HandBrake 0.10.1 2015030800
  Duration: 01:59:10.12, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 6868 kb/s
    Stream #0:0(und): Video: h264 (High) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p(tv, bt709), 1920x1080 [SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9], 6017 kb/s, 29.97 fps, 29.97 tbr, 90k tbn, 180k tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : VideoHandler
    Stream #0:1(und): Audio: aac (LC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp, 320 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : Stereo
    Stream #0:2(und): Audio: aac (LC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 48000 Hz, 5.1, fltp, 320 kb/s
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : Surround
    Stream #0:3(und): Audio: aac (LC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp, 192 kb/s
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : Stereo
Input #1, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from 'B.mp4':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : mp42
    minor_version   : 512
    compatible_brands: isomiso2avc1mp41
    encoder         : HandBrake 0.10.1 2015030800
  Duration: 01:12:28.48, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 6846 kb/s
    Stream #1:0(und): Video: h264 (High) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p(tv, bt709), 1920x1080 [SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9], 6001 kb/s, 29.97 fps, 29.97 tbr, 90k tbn, 180k tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : VideoHandler
    Stream #1:1(und): Audio: aac (LC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp, 320 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : Stereo
    Stream #1:2(und): Audio: aac (LC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 48000 Hz, 5.1, fltp, 320 kb/s
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : Surround
    Stream #1:3(und): Audio: aac (LC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp, 192 kb/s
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : Stereo
Input #2, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from 'C.mp4':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : mp42
    minor_version   : 512
    compatible_brands: isomiso2avc1mp41
    encoder         : HandBrake 0.10.1 2015030800
  Duration: 00:58:55.53, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 6850 kb/s
    Stream #2:0(und): Video: h264 (High) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p(tv, bt709), 1920x1080 [SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9], 6005 kb/s, 29.97 fps, 29.97 tbr, 90k tbn, 180k tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : VideoHandler
    Stream #2:1(und): Audio: aac (LC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp, 319 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : Stereo
    Stream #2:2(und): Audio: aac (LC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 48000 Hz, 5.1, fltp, 319 kb/s
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : Surround
    Stream #2:3(und): Audio: aac (LC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp, 192 kb/s
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : Stereo
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:0 (h264) -> concat:in0:v0
  Stream #0:1 (aac) -> concat:in0:a0
  Stream #0:2 (aac) -> concat:in0:a1
  Stream #0:3 (aac) -> concat:in0:a2
  Stream #1:0 (h264) -> concat:in1:v0
  Stream #1:1 (aac) -> concat:in1:a0
  Stream #1:2 (aac) -> concat:in1:a1
  Stream #1:3 (aac) -> concat:in1:a2
  Stream #2:0 (h264) -> concat:in2:v0
  Stream #2:1 (aac) -> concat:in2:a0
  Stream #2:2 (aac) -> concat:in2:a1
  Stream #2:3 (aac) -> concat:in2:a2
  concat:out:v0 -> Stream #0:0 (libx264)
  concat:out:a0 -> Stream #0:1 (aac)
  concat:out:a1 -> Stream #0:2 (aac)
  concat:out:a2 -> Stream #0:3 (aac)
Press [q] to stop, [?] for help
[libx264 @ 000001930c898980] using SAR=1/1
[libx264 @ 000001930c898980] using cpu capabilities: MMX2 SSE2Fast SSSE3 SSE4.2 AVX
[libx264 @ 000001930c898980] profile High, level 4.0, 4:2:0, 8-bit
[libx264 @ 000001930c898980] 264 - core 157 r2935 545de2f - H.264/MPEG-4 AVC codec - Copyleft 2003-2018 - http://www.videolan.org/x264.html - options: cabac=1 ref=3 deblock=1:0:0 analyse=0x3:0x113 me=hex subme=7 psy=1 psy_rd=1.00:0.00 mixed_ref=1 me_range=16 chroma_me=1 trellis=1 8x8dct=1 cqm=0 deadzone=21,11 fast_pskip=1 chroma_qp_offset=-2 threads=12 lookahead_threads=2 sliced_threads=0 nr=0 decimate=1 interlaced=0 bluray_compat=0 constrained_intra=0 bframes=3 b_pyramid=2 b_adapt=1 b_bias=0 direct=1 weightb=1 open_gop=0 weightp=2 keyint=250 keyint_min=25 scenecut=40 intra_refresh=0 rc_lookahead=40 rc=crf mbtree=1 crf=23.0 qcomp=0.60 qpmin=0 qpmax=69 qpstep=4 ip_ratio=1.40 aq=1:1.00
Output #0, mp4, to 'output.mp4':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : mp42
    minor_version   : 512
    compatible_brands: isomiso2avc1mp41
    encoder         : Lavf58.20.100
    Stream #0:0: Video: h264 (libx264) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p(progressive), 1920x1080 [SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9], q=-1--1, 29.97 fps, 30k tbn, 29.97 tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      encoder         : Lavc58.35.100 libx264
    Side data:
      cpb: bitrate max/min/avg: 0/0/0 buffer size: 0 vbv_delay: -1
    Stream #0:1: Audio: aac (LC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp, 128 kb/s
    Metadata:
      encoder         : Lavc58.35.100 aac
    Stream #0:2: Audio: aac (LC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 48000 Hz, 5.1, fltp, 341 kb/s
    Metadata:
      encoder         : Lavc58.35.100 aac
    Stream #0:3: Audio: aac (LC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp, 128 kb/s
    Metadata:
      encoder         : Lavc58.35.100 aac
[aac @ 000001930d3a88c0] skip_data_stream_element: Input buffer exhausted before END element found
Error while decoding stream #0:1: Invalid data found when processing input
[aac @ 000001930c89a4c0] Number of bands (48) exceeds limit (47).ate=6048.4kbits/s dup=1 drop=0 speed=0.916x
Error while decoding stream #2:1: Invalid data found when processing input
frame=450571 fps= 28 q=-1.0 Lsize=11204203kB time=04:10:34.13 bitrate=6105.1kbits/s dup=1 drop=0 speed=0.939x
video:10071486kB audio:1099256kB subtitle:0kB other streams:0kB global headers:0kB muxing overhead: 0.299544%
[libx264 @ 000001930c898980] frame I:4679  Avg QP:20.30  size:103274
[libx264 @ 000001930c898980] frame P:125629 Avg QP:22.82  size: 41052
[libx264 @ 000001930c898980] frame B:320263 Avg QP:25.08  size: 14590
[libx264 @ 000001930c898980] consecutive B-frames:  2.3%  6.0%  8.8% 83.0%
[libx264 @ 000001930c898980] mb I  I16..4: 16.4% 78.4%  5.2%
[libx264 @ 000001930c898980] mb P  I16..4:  7.0% 17.1%  1.1%  P16..4: 43.0%  9.7%  4.9%  0.0%  0.0%    skip:17.3%
[libx264 @ 000001930c898980] mb B  I16..4:  0.8%  1.7%  0.1%  B16..8: 39.4%  3.6%  0.7%  direct: 4.3%  skip:49.4%  L0:43.8% L1:50.2% BI: 6.0%
[libx264 @ 000001930c898980] 8x8 transform intra:68.6% inter:84.9%
[libx264 @ 000001930c898980] coded y,uvDC,uvAC intra: 40.3% 64.9% 17.2% inter: 12.9% 24.2% 0.4%
[libx264 @ 000001930c898980] i16 v,h,dc,p: 40% 22% 10% 28%
[libx264 @ 000001930c898980] i8 v,h,dc,ddl,ddr,vr,hd,vl,hu: 28% 15% 23%  5%  6%  7%  5%  6%  5%
[libx264 @ 000001930c898980] i4 v,h,dc,ddl,ddr,vr,hd,vl,hu: 26% 16% 16%  6%  9%  9%  7%  6%  5%
[libx264 @ 000001930c898980] i8c dc,h,v,p: 48% 20% 26%  6%
[libx264 @ 000001930c898980] Weighted P-Frames: Y:8.6% UV:6.4%
[libx264 @ 000001930c898980] ref P L0: 58.8% 12.5% 19.8%  8.4%  0.4%
[libx264 @ 000001930c898980] ref B L0: 88.5%  9.1%  2.4%
[libx264 @ 000001930c898980] ref B L1: 96.9%  3.1%
[libx264 @ 000001930c898980] kb/s:5487.92
[aac @ 000001930c899280] Qavg: 212.043
[aac @ 000001930d1cfbc0] Qavg: 211.329
[aac @ 000001930d1ce080] Qavg: 228.685
```

This is the output when trying the concat demuxer, which also produces an unplayable file.

```
ffmpeg -f concat -safe 0 -i mylist.txt -map 0 -c copy concat2.mp4
ffmpeg version 4.1.1 Copyright (c) 2000-2019 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 8.2.1 (GCC) 20190212
  configuration: --enable-gpl --enable-version3 --enable-sdl2 --enable-fontconfig --enable-gnutls --enable-iconv --enable-libass --enable-libbluray --enable-libfreetype --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libopus --enable-libshine --enable-libsnappy --enable-libsoxr --enable-libtheora --enable-libtwolame --enable-libvpx --enable-libwavpack --enable-libwebp --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable-libxml2 --enable-libzimg --enable-lzma --enable-zlib --enable-gmp --enable-libvidstab --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvo-amrwbenc --enable-libmysofa --enable-libspeex --enable-libxvid --enable-libaom --enable-libmfx --enable-amf --enable-ffnvcodec --enable-cuvid --enable-d3d11va --enable-nvenc --enable-nvdec --enable-dxva2 --enable-avisynth
  libavutil      56. 22.100 / 56. 22.100
  libavcodec     58. 35.100 / 58. 35.100
  libavformat    58. 20.100 / 58. 20.100
  libavdevice    58.  5.100 / 58.  5.100
  libavfilter     7. 40.101 /  7. 40.101
  libswscale      5.  3.100 /  5.  3.100
  libswresample   3.  3.100 /  3.  3.100
  libpostproc    55.  3.100 / 55.  3.100
[mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2 @ 0000025ca95f2dc0] Auto-inserting h264_mp4toannexb bitstream filter
Input #0, concat, from 'mylist.txt':
  Duration: N/A, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 6850 kb/s
    Stream #0:0(und): Video: h264 (High) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p(tv, bt709), 1920x1080 [SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9], 6017 kb/s, 29.97 fps, 29.97 tbr, 90k tbn, 180k tbc
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : VideoHandler
    Stream #0:1(und): Audio: aac (LC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp, 320 kb/s
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : Stereo
    Stream #0:2(und): Audio: aac (LC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 48000 Hz, 5.1, fltp, 320 kb/s
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : Surround
    Stream #0:3(und): Audio: aac (LC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp, 192 kb/s
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : Stereo
Output #0, mp4, to 'concat2.mp4':
  Metadata:
    encoder         : Lavf58.20.100
    Stream #0:0(und): Video: h264 (High) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p(tv, bt709), 1920x1080 [SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9], q=2-31, 6017 kb/s, 29.97 fps, 29.97 tbr, 90k tbn, 90k tbc
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : VideoHandler
    Stream #0:1(und): Audio: aac (LC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp, 320 kb/s
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : Stereo
    Stream #0:2(und): Audio: aac (LC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 48000 Hz, 5.1, fltp, 320 kb/s
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : Surround
    Stream #0:3(und): Audio: aac (LC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp, 192 kb/s
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : Stereo
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (copy)
  Stream #0:1 -> #0:1 (copy)
  Stream #0:2 -> #0:2 (copy)
  Stream #0:3 -> #0:3 (copy)
Press [q] to stop, [?] for help
[mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2 @ 0000025ca95f9480] Auto-inserting h264_mp4toannexb bitstream filter4x
[mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2 @ 0000025ca95f9480] Auto-inserting h264_mp4toannexb bitstream filter5x
frame=450570 fps=1251 q=-1.0 Lsize=12591157kB time=04:10:34.11 bitrate=6860.8kbits/s speed=41.7x
video:11029679kB audio:1527897kB subtitle:0kB other streams:0kB global headers:0kB muxing overhead: 0.267411%
```

Comment: Show the complete log.

Comment: It's a lot of so I reproduced the steps and uploaded here, I hope this works

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1GjQo6sqCC-BLn2YkDQQw7VJ1HrB4yPNy/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Does the output seem ok? The inputs superficially look like they can be concatenated with the [concat demuxer](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-formats.html#concat): `ffmpeg -f concat -i input.txt -map 0 -c copy output.mp4`. Have you tried that?

Comment: Tried it this morning, it also produced an unplayable file. When I open it on MPC or VLC it says "File not Found"

Comment: Solved!  It was an issue with file ownership, after taking ownership of the folder the file became playable.
Thanks!

Comment: You can make that the answer to your question.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try this:

- **scale** = Scale (resize) the input video, using the libswscale library(scale=w:h)
- **setsar** = The setsar filter sets the Sample (aka Pixel) Aspect Ratio for the filter output video.
- **concat** = Concatenate audio and video streams, joining them together one after the other.
- **n** = Set the number of segments. Default is 2.
- **v** = Set the number of output video streams, that is also the number of video streams in each segment. Default is 1
- **a** = Set the number of output audio streams, that is also the number of audio streams in each segment. Default is 0.
- **ab** = Indicates the audio bitrate
- **ac** = Set the number of audio channels. For output streams it is set by default to the number of input audio channels. For input streams this option only makes sense for audio grabbing devices and raw demuxers and is mapped to the corresponding demuxer options.
- **ar** = Set the audio sampling frequency. For output streams it is set by default to the frequency of the corresponding input stream. For input streams this option only makes sense for audio grabbing devices and raw demuxers and is mapped to the corresponding demuxer options
- **vcodec** = Set the video codec
- **libx264** = encodes all streams with libx264 and copies all streams
- **crf** = As others have pointed out (Thanks all), the values will depend on which encoder you're using.
                   For x264 your valid range is 0-51:
                   Where 0 is lossless, 23 is default, and 51 is worst possible. A lower value is a higher quality
- **s** = resolution of the given video file

  ```
   //command

   ffmpeg -y -i INPUT.mp4 -i INPUT.mp4 -filter_complex [0:v]scale=1080x640,setsar=1:1[v0];[1:v]scale=1080x640,setsar=1:1[v1];[v0][0:a][v1][1:a] concat=n=2:v=1:a=1 -ab 48000 -ac 2 -ar 22050 -s 1080x640 -vcodec libx264 -crf 10 -q 4 -preset ultrafast OUTPUT.mp4
  ```

Comment: This doesn't address the issue in the question.